# Equivalence classes of a map

Tags: complex-numbers, proof-explanation

I'm watching one of Benedict Gross's abstract algebra lectures. After introducing the fibre over an element (essentially, to my understanding, an inverse image of an element in the codomain), he gives an example of the function
\begin{align*}
f: \mathbb{R} \to S^1, \; t \longmapsto e^{i(2\pi t)}.
\end{align*}
He argues that this map is surjective onto the unit circle, which I believe: a point on the unit circle is exactly of the form $e^{i \theta}$, so I can just pick an appropriate $t$ to capture its polar angle. He then treats $S^1$, the image of this map, as a set of equivalence classes wherein we identify an equivalence class with a point in the image and, in particular, the fibre of that element. So the fibre over $1$ or the equivalence class we identify with $1$ is the set of integers $t$, which makes sense, because any polar angle that is an integer multiple of $2\pi$ will give $(1,0)$ in the complex plane, e.g., for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$,
\begin{align*}
e^{i(2\pi n)}  =\cos(2\pi n) + i \sin (2\pi n) = 1 + i 0 = 1.
\end{align*}
What he said next confused me, though. He comments that the set of equivalence classes are $[0,1]$. I believe he was speaking about the domain and suggesting that every element of $S^1$ has a preimage in $[0,1]$ so we can identify points in the image with a point in $[0,1]$. I can't prove this for myself, though, and it's very likely I'm misunderstanding.

I'd appreciate if someone could clear this up.

Comment: The circle is homomorphic to $\mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Z}$. Think of this homomorphism as winding the real line around the circle with the $0$ in the reals fixed to the point $1$ in the complex plane.

Comment: So we can write $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ as the set of equivalence classes $[0,1)$, which I understand. The rest, including the inclusion of $1$ and even the geometry, I don't quite understand.

Comment: I don't understand the inclusion of $1$ in $[0,1]$ either. Think of this as traveling around the circle once then resetting once you get back where you started. Each integer marks a single trip around the circle which is why the fiber above $0$ (ie the kernel) is the integers.

Comment: So $0$ and $1$ are the same equivalence class then since both are integers? And since $f([0,1)= S^1$, we can call identify every point in the image with something in $[0,1)$, correct? If this is right, the only thing I don't fully understand (which is another thing Professor Gross said and which I believe you and Berci were alluding to) is the idea that geometrically, we can take any two points in this interval and get a circle, perhaps by gluing. This is the one area I'm still confused on, but the rest is clear.

Comment: Yeah they're in the same equivalence class because they're integers. Every point on the circle can be identified by some point in $t \in [0,1)$ which will be $2\pi t$ radians around the unit circle. For any $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$ then it is represented by $t =x - \lfloor x \rfloor$  which is the fractional part of $x$. Every interval $[n,n+1)$ for some integer $n$ will be a circle and all these intervals are sort of glued together in the group.

Comment: I apologize if I'm being dense. I understand everything except for the last sentence. My only points of confusion are: how do we know that every interval $[n, n+1)$ is a circle, and what do you mean by "glued together"? Thank you again for all your help.

Comment: Analogously we could consider the integers modulo $n$ for some $n$. We can choose the representatives $\{0,1,2,...,n-2,n-1\}$ but this choice is arbitrary and we could have picked any member of the cosets associated with those elements. The reason $[n,n+1)$ represents a circle is because when we pass to the quotient we forget the integer part and we can use it as the representatives from the cosets. Circles are periodic with period $2\pi$ so once you loop around them once you start over at the beginning again.

Comment: Where exactly does periodicity come into play? I know that $\cos$ and $\sin$ are periodic with period $2\pi$, but where exactly does it enter into $[n, n+1)$ being a representative interval?

Comment: The periodic nature of $\mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Z}$ follows from the quotient group since $x=y$ if and only if $x-y \in \mathbb{Z}$. Say we have $1/2$ then the coset containing $1/2$ is $n + 1/2$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. You can choose any representative from the coset even if they're not in the same interval since it won't change the fact that $n_1 + 1/2 - (n_2 + 1/2)=n_1 - n_2$ is an integer. Since $n=0$ for all the integers they are indistinguishable.  Using $[0,1)$ and add $1/2 + 3/4 = 5/4 = 1/4$  If we use $[n,n+1)$ we get the same with $n$ added to every term.

Comment: This makes sense to me for the arithmetic mod $n$, but is it also true that $e^{i(2\pi x)} = e^{i (2\pi (x + n)}$?

Comment: $e^{i(2\pi x)} = e^{i 2 \pi x}1 = e^{i 2 \pi x}e^{i 2\pi n}=e^{i 2\pi (x + n)}$

Comment: This clears everything up. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is correct: if we restrict $f$ to the right-open interval $[0,1)$, we actually get a one-to-one correspondence to the points on the circle, because angles are measured modulo $2\pi$.

If we apply the exact same procedure with the restriction of $f$ to the closed interval $[0,1]$, we obtain the quotient $[0,1]/\sim$ where $0\sim 1$, which is again the circle:  if we glue together the end of an elastic string, we do get a circle.

Comment: It's possible that I am misunderstanding here. So by periodicity, $f([0,1) = S^1$. In that case, wouldn't the equivalence classes be $S^1$? I'm also not sure what you mean by the notation $[0,1]/0$. Would you mind clarifying? Thank you for the help.